# Not able to get data in spark using socket programming in JAVA

Tags: java, sockets, apache-spark, spark-streaming

I had written one spark job to listen on on socket on a specific port, for this I had used JavaStreamingContext in my Spark code. Please refer my spark code as below -

```
SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("ApmpathAggregationSocket").setMaster("local[2]");
    JavaStreamingContext ssc = new JavaStreamingContext(sparkConf,new Duration(2000));
    JavaReceiverInputDStream<String> lines = ssc.socketTextStream("servername",9999);
    lines.print();
    ssc.start();
    ssc.awaitTermination();
```

Later I had written a java code to connet to this port 9999 and send some data, my requirement is like I need to to send some of the data from my java code using socket and spark job should get the data their, but I am not getting the data on the Spark side. I could see that the Spark job is connected to the socket and it is listening on port 9999, but when I am sending something using socket programming in java I am not able to do that. Please refer my below Socket Java code --

```
    try {
        ServerSocket socket = new ServerSocket(9999);
        Socket clientSock = socket.accept();
        Socket clientSock2 = new Socket("servername",9999);
        //DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(clientSock.getInputStream()); 
        DataOutputStream dout=new DataOutputStream(clientSock2.getOutputStream());  
        BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));              
        String str="";  
        while(!str.equals("stop")){ 
            str=br.readLine();
            dout.writeUTF(str);  
            dout.flush();  
        }
        dout.close(); 
        socket.close();
        clientSock.close();
        clientSock2.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Can somebody please help me in achieving this as I am new to Spark. Thanks.